# jquery event capture

Tags: jquery

I cannot find a way to make sure the function is complete before checking for an event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready( function() {

var cesc = new flickrshow('flickrbox', {
   'autoplay':true,
   'hide_buttons':false,
   'interval':3500,
   'page':1,
   'per_page':10,
   'user':'53335537@N04' });

jQuery('li').hover(function(){ console.log (jQuery(this)); }); 

});
</script>
```

this script run on : http://www.notrepanorama.com/

the box is created, then populated with images and if i hover on the images, the

dont log into the console, but the

in the menu are... so i think it's because the box is not populated when the function execute....

any solution to that ?

Comment: I think there are some missing part in your text :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    jQuery('li').bind('mouseover',function(){
       // code for mouser over
    }).bind('mouseout',function (){
       // code for mouse out
    });

whatever i understood from your question(which is unclear), this is my solution.
```